# Android webView InAppBrowserFragment error encroachment menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I have can `WebView` in `Fragment`, when move tab `Fragment`,and  I touch `Button` aboutUs--> move in `Fragment` AboutUs; I repeat about 10times.

Error is same picture.
can everyone help me?. Thank :

Code `Fragment` load `WebView` :

```
public class InAppBrowserFragment
        extends BaseFragment {

    private static final String LINK_PAGE = "linkPage";
    private static final String TITLE_ACTION_BAR = "titleActionBar";

    @InjectView(R.id.web_settings)
    WebView mWebViewSettings;
    @InjectView(R.id.actionbar_settings_sub)
    ActionBar mActionBar;
    @InjectView(R.id.img__settings_background)
    ImageView mImgSettingsBackground;

    /**
     * Static method used to create an instance for this fragment.
     *
     * @return New instance of Fragment.
     */
    public static InAppBrowserFragment newInstance(String titleActionBar,
                                                  String linkPage) {
        final InAppBrowserFragment fragment = new InAppBrowserFragment();
        final Bundle data = new Bundle();
        if (titleActionBar != null) {
            data.putString(LINK_PAGE,
                           linkPage);
            data.putString(TITLE_ACTION_BAR,
                           titleActionBar);
        }

        // Attach data with fragment.
        fragment.setArguments(data);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
        return R.layout.fragment_in_app_browser;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initUi(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String titleActionBar = getArguments().getString(TITLE_ACTION_BAR);
        //set background
        CommonUtil.displayImage(getActivity(),
                                CommonUtil.getDrawableResource(R.drawable.img_random_frontpage_1),
                                this.mImgSettingsBackground,
                                0,
                                0,
                                0,
                                true,
                                false,
                                null);
        //set UI Action Bar
        this.mActionBar.setupUI(null,
                                titleActionBar,
                                R.drawable.ab_ic_back,
                                0,
                                "");
        this.mActionBar.setButtonRightPadding(0);
        this.mActionBar.setButtonLeftListener(new ActionBar.IActionBarButtonLeftListener() {
            @Override
            public void onButtonLeftClicked(final View view) {
                popBack(true);
                mWebViewSettings.canGoBack();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void loadData(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String linkPage = getArguments().getString(LINK_PAGE);
        // Init webview setting
        WebSettings settings = mWebViewSettings.getSettings();

        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebViewSettings.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

            }
        });
        mWebViewSettings.loadUrl(linkPage);
    }
}
```

Conrect:
[image]

Inconrect:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i fix sucess :(**set wrap_content for Webview** )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             style="@style/CreateTrips.Widget.ScreenContent.Fragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img__settings_background"
        style="@style/CreateTrips.Widget.BackgroundImage"
        android:contentDescription="@null"/>

    <com.createtrips.ui.widgets.ActionBar
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_settings_sub"
        style="@style/CreateTrips.Widget.ActionBar"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/widget_action_bar_height"
        >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```